# Cannot Mock RandomStringUtils Class method random

Tags: java, spring, random, apache-commons

I am using RandomStringUtils class from apache commons lang3 library. I am facing issue while mocking the random method of it.

below is my example class with simple method generatePassword.

```
public class Example() {

    public String generatePassword() {
       
     final String randomDevicePass = RandomStringUtils.random(10, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
     
     System.out.println(randomDevicePass)
    
     return randomDevicePass;
        
    }

}
```

below is my Test Class, by which I am running the test case.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleTest() {

    @InjectMocks
    private Example Example;
    
    @Mock
    RandomStringutils randomStringutils;

    @Test
    public void givenCharacters_returnStringPassword() {

           Mockito.when(randomStringUtils.random(Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("asdf");

    Assertions.assertEquals("asdf", example.generatePassword());
    }

}
```

It gives below error:

```
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
```

I am not sure how to mock the Java inbuilt apache commons library class. not sure can we use spy? or something ...can anyone helps me on this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does Mockito support mocking static methods? Note that even though you're calling the method "via" a reference (`randomStringUtils.random`), that will actually resolve to just a static method call as if you'd written `RandomStringUtils.random`.

Comment: Mocking static methods is possible, but requires a different configuration. See https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

Comment: Remove `@Mock` and just put `@Autowired` as below:

    `@Autowired
    RandomStringutils randomStringutils;`

Comment: Tried putting @Autowired but it gives null pointer since it is unit test class not component or service class

Answer (score 2):

It is usually somewhat of a code smell whenever you need to mock a static method. However, there are ways of doing it within the Mockito library.

First, add a file to your test resources directory in a new folder `mockito-extensions`. The file name should be `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`. The file needs to have the single line: mock-maker-inline

Then you are ready to add a static mock through Mockito.mockStatic like this:

```
        try (MockedStatic<RandomStringUtils> utils = Mockito.mockStatic(RandomStringUtils.class)) {
            utils.when(() -> RandomStringUtils.random(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("asdf");

            Assertions.assertEquals("asdf", example.generatePassword());
        }
```